# Configure specific package for generated classes in ADT / ant build

Tags: java, android, ant, adt

I'm developing an application for various customers that use exactly the same code (it just displays a `WebView`). The only differences are one config file, the icon and the android package name, all generated via a custom ant task.

If I run the ant release target or build the project in eclipse, the generated Java classes (like `R`) are generated in a package named like the android package. As a result, imports of these classes in my project are invalid, because their package has changed.

Newsnet.java

```
package ch.newsnet.app;

import ch.newsnet.app.R; // <- cannot be found after build

public class Newsnet extends FragmentActivity {
    //...
}
```

Running my custom ant target will set my android package to `ch.customer1.app`, wich makes R a class of package `ch.customer1.app`. But I want it always to be `ch.newsnet.app`. How can I achieve that in a) the ant build and b) in the eclipse builder? I don' want to setup 20+ projects and maintain their buildfile and resources when I can have all in one code base.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you set up a library project containing all your logic - and then create a shell project for each customer.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to avoid. I would have lots of duplicate configuration code

Comment: Class `R` is auto-generated by Android and it will always be in the package of the app - you don't have any control over it.  You can try renaming/moving/editing it afterwards, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: So how would a library project help me then? I would use the import of the generated `R` in my activity, which I of course would have in the library project, so I'm still facing the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who face the same issue, I solved this problem as follows (allthough it's not the best solution, but it worked for me):

I created the ant target moveGeneratedFiles, where I copy the generated package to the correct one, replace the package name and delete the generated one (which will not really work in eclipse because the classes will be generated again).

```
<target name="moveGeneratedFiles">
    <loadproperties>
      <file file="assets/customer.properties"/>
    </loadproperties>
    <copy todir="gen/ch/newsnet/app" overwrite="true">
        <fileset dir="gen/ch/${customer.name}/app" />
    </copy>
    <replace dir="gen/ch/newsnet/app" token="package ch.${customer.name}.app;" value="package ch.newsnet.app;" />
    <delete>
        <fileset dir="gen/ch/${customer.name}/app" />
    </delete>
</target>
```

In the project properties, I added an ant builder executing this target so the generated classes will be synced after saving.